# Only retrieving first 2 values when parsing json data

Tags: python, json, rest, dictionary

Hi I'm trying to parse the feed from the matchbook.com api. I can't post the whole feed because it's too long, but this is the code I'm using:

```
r15 = 

s.get('https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events/488126519970009')
r16 = r15.json()

pprint.pprint (r16)

for market_id in r16['markets']:
    print (market_id['runners'][0]['market-id'])

for runner in r16['markets']:
    print (runner['runners'][0]['name'])
```

I can't seem to return more than the first 2 results and I don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is using only the first runners.

Iterate all runners:

```
for market in r16['markets']:
    for runner in market['runners']:
        print(runner['name'])
```

prints:

```
5 Firmament
7 Mitchum Swagger
2 Kool Kompany
1 Jallota
6 Kaspersky
4 Big Baz
3 Beach Bar
1 Jallota
2 Kool Kompany
3 Beach Bar
4 Big Baz
5 Firmament
6 Kaspersky
7 Mitchum Swagger
```